# Android Hidden Process

Tags: android

creating a process in android which must not be listed in the PROCESS LISTING / TASK MANAGER etc ...

Or a method of code injection were i can start a new PROCESS from another APK

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be I've miss understood your question but can you precise the question context ? At first I thought that  was a "how to create a malware ?" question .

Answer (score 2):

> creating a process in android which must not be listed in the PROCESS LISTING / TASK MANAGER etc

Fortunately, this is not possible, except perhaps via custom firmware.

> Or a method of code injection were i can start a new PROCESS from another APK

You can launch an activity in another application via `startActivity()` and an appropriate `Intent`. That other application will run in its own process.